# A propriedade de CSS Box-Shadow afeta a performance da página e renderização dos elementos?

Tags: html, css, desempenho, acessibilidade, usabilidade

Sei que a propriedade `box-shadow` é relativamente antiga, e amplamente usada. Mas ao usa-la em excesso, digo ao aplicar `box-shadow` em 100 elementos na mesma página eu tenho perca de desempenho?

Fiz esse primeiro print com mais de 400 divs, e repare no tempo de `rendering` Ultrapassou o limite da linha vermelha... Assim como o `load` foi mas lento, provavelmente por ter mais código "bruto" no documento
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora com cerca de 50 div veja nas marcações em vermelho que o render é mais sutil, nem a linha vermelha aparece. **Repare nas setas vermelhas dessa imagem e compare com a outra acima**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
*Aparentemente os FPS nos dois casos ficaram em 100% (60fps)*

Percebo que quando tenho um uso "abusivo" desse propriedade, e até mesmo quando tenho animações onde os elementos têm `box-shadow` a maquina da uma "gargalada" de desempenho, principalmente em mobile...

- Esse questão do **`box-shadow` *vs* desempenho de hardware** realmente procede realmente afeta as animações e o Scroll da página?
- Uma alternativa seria usar a propriedade `filter: drop-shadow()`?
- Esse fato pode prejudicar a experiencia do usuário no que tange a Acessibilidade e o resultado de SEO com uma página que renderiza mais lentamente?

Artigo de referência que encontrei: https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/css-box-shadow-can-slow-down-scrolling-d8ea47ec6867

***Código que usei no teste***

```css
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #999;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Ótima pergunta, pena que só da pra recompensar respostas

Comment: Cara estamos falando de milesimos de segundo, coisa que não  há aplicabilidade pratica,  o que no mais pode estar pesando sua renderização é o  numero de divs e não a propriedade em si.

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam valeu jovem! Vamos ver se aparece alguma resposta que contemple alguns dos pontos, muitas vezes focamos no layout e perdemos no desempenho... como podemos medir isso né...

Comment: @MarcosBrinner se vc pensar que nem todo mundo tem um iPhone e que existem dispositivos mobile com baixíssima capacidade de processamento, o abuso dessa e de outras propriedades pode ser um fator preocupante, por isso fiz a pergunta... As vezes alguém tem algo mais concreto para compartilhar.

Comment: Na verdade não sei dizer se afeta ou não, mas é uma ótima pergunta e tenho muito interesse em saber a resposta eheheh.

Comment: @RenanOsorio eu dei una pesquisada, e o assunto eh ate bem discutido e documentado por ai, mas eh meio complexo, não achei nada em português, ou que tivesse uma didática de fac entendimento. Vamos ver se alguém com mais informações colabora com uma resposta.